# How to generate this timestamp using Java

Tags: java

20160222082641Z

This kind of timestamp is logged using some LDAP functionality. I need to duplicate it in a Java program.

My team members are unable to tell me how to do this or really give me any kind of useful help. Would anyone be familiar with how to generate this in Java? Thanks

Comment: that is a formattted date...

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: It would be helpful for you to parse that time stamp into its components.  I see the first four digits are likely a year, but after that it becomes unclear what the fields are, or mean.

Comment: Looks like YYYYMMDDHHMMSS and Z for Zulu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SimpleDateformat:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

String ldapDate = format.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + "Z";

System.out.println(ldapDate);
```

Comment: I think they want UTC time (Z), not the local time.

Comment: This is easy enough to overcome, the answer has been modified

Comment: `new Date()` is much more succinct than using a Calendar to get the current date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8, the following imports are needed:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import static java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC;
```

Using Java 8, the following code should work:

```
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(UTC);
    String timeString = now.toString();
    String strOut = timeString.substring(0,4)
            + timeString.substring(5,7) + timeString.substring(8,10)
            + timeString.substring(11,13) + timeString.substring(14,16)
            + timeString.substring(17,19) + "Z";

    System.out.println(now);
    System.out.println(strOut);
```